# Как сохранить файл по определенному пути?

Tags: java, android, файлы

Требуется сохранить файл по определенному заданному пути или просто в общедоступную папку android, либо просто что то похожее, куда можно получить доступ обычному пользователю, не так, как на примере с OutputStreamWriter, который сохраняет файл в папку /data/data

Comment: смотрите ContentResolver метод insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сохранения файла в папку на Android можно использовать следующий код:

```
String fileName = "example.txt";
String content = "Hello, World!";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(content.getBytes());
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Здесь мы создаем объект `File` с путем к внешнему хранилищу `(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())`, указываем имя файла и записываем в него содержимое. В данном случае мы записываем строку "Hello, World!".

Однако, стоит учесть что для доступа к внешнему хранилищу требуется соответствующее разрешение в манифесте приложения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```